# What does recv() return in this case?

Tags: networking

If the sendeer send N bytes and then closed the socket
and the reader is waiting to receive the N bytes, I think it will receive N bytes, the errno will not be set and the subsequent recv wil return 0. Correct?

Comment: That is correct, except that the N bytes may not all be received together in a single `recv()`.